# How to get the X position of a transform and convert it into a float in Unity2D

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to get the x position of a gameobject in unity2D and converting the data of the X position into a float which I can use to detect if the position is -24 or 24 and then taking the x position of that gameobject and setting it back to 0.

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSh3N.png)

**I've no idea how to do it in any other way**
**Error Messages In Console**
Error *CS1612* Cannot modify the return value of 'Transform.position' because it is not a variable  Assembly-CSharp

Comment: welcome to SO.  i'm glad you got an answer. next time please include the code in a code block rather than an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You inverted the position and your X variable. Change it so it is
 `X = Background.transform.position.x;` so you assign the position to X.

Answer (score 1):

You should flip line 17
X = Background.transform.x;